# How to modify or create custom contact form 7 select options

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 and here is the actual contact form 7 code to display the select drop down

```
<div class="select-wpr">[select* program id:program first_as_label required "Choose your program of interest"]</div></div>
<div class="full-width">
<div class="select-wpr">[select* campus id:campus first_as_label "Choose campus"]</div>
</div>
```

Where can I go and modify the actual select drop down options? I want to add `<optgroup>` to the select options but can't find where to go and modify that. Where is that located in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Contact Form 7 plugin.  Instead you can make use of the dynamic_dropdown tag offered by the CF7 plugin extension, [CF7 Smart Grid-layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/).  This allows you to create a dynamic dropdown, which has an option to filter the drodown's options, and therefore create a custom set of options,

```
add_filter('cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options', 'custom_options');
function custom_options($options){
  return "
    <optgroup>
      <option>...</option>
    </optgroup>
  ";
}
```

the plugin enables filter helpers once you insert a tag field in your form.  these helpers have more information to help you with their functionality.